# how to get cursor from name of cursor?

Tags: c#

like below that we get color , I Want set the Cursor property of Button

```
Color red = Color.FromName("Red");
    button1.BackColor = red;
```

may be something like this:

```
   String x = "Hand"
    button1.Cursor = Cursor.FromName(x);
```

**Here is simple example:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37101840/6306993

> ```
> CursorConverter cConverter = new CursorConverter();
> Cursor c = (Cursor) cConverter.ConvertFromString("Hand");
> this.button1.Cursor = c;
> ```

Comment: `Cursor.Pointer` ?

Comment: using string to property.  I take the xml files.

Answer (score 3):

as my understanding, you are looking for how to set Cursor for button depend in existing variable. Please see the example below:

```
Cursor x = Cursors.Hand;
button1.Cursor = x;
```

if you still get error please check again "Cursors" not "Cursor" in the first line.

Comment: I take the xml files. 
Example : 
String ex = "None";
button1.Cursor = ex ; 
Example 2 : 
String ex2 = "Hand";
button1.Cursor = ex2; as

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are looking for `CursorConverter`.

Here is simple example:

```
CursorConverter cConverter = new CursorConverter();
Cursor c = (Cursor) cConverter.ConvertFromString("Hand");
this.button1.Cursor = c;
```

More information:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursorconverter(v=vs.110).aspx